# Digital filter: selection

Tags: digital-filters, sensor

I am going through digital filter design. But I really get confused with so many

1. **Digital filters** :

   - IIR
   - FIR
   - Moving Average
   - Linear phase filter
   - Allpass filter
   - Comb filter
2. **Analog filter:**

   - Buterworth
   - Chebychev
   - Elliptic

Is their any specific application where each filter is used ?

I suppose biomedical signal sensing or temperature sensor value filtering use digital filter (?).

Please suggest.

Comment: This is a huuuuge question, and it reflects that albeit you've encountered many different terms, you're lacking the typical signal theory basics. So, maybe, get an undergrad textbook on signals and systems?

Comment: ok, please rephrase your question according to your last statement. Get rid of the general digital filter selection part and specifically ask for digital filter types that're applied to biomedical sensing (or temperature sensor) applications. Furthermore try to **specify** your signal characteristics and processing purpose as much (mathematical) as possible, so that the selection and the design can become meaningful as it will be fitting the purpose. If you cannot do this, it means that you have more fundamental problems before the selection of the filter as Marcus have pointed.

Comment: this should help you : http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2017/02/choosing-a-filter-fir-or-iir-understanding-the-design-perspective/ but it's just one amongst so many resources online... As Marcus and Fat32 said, you probably need to do some research by yourself as your question is too generic

Comment: By the way, moving average and linear phase filters are FIR and Butterworth/Comb/Chebychev/elliptic can be implemented as IIR.